# couchdb: is there an identity list function?

Tags: couchdb

I'm learning about [list functions](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html) in couchdb, and I'm wondering what the identity function looks like, if one exists. (i.e. a list that emits the same output as a raw view)

If you understand list functions, could you help me write one?

I expect it would look something like

```
function(head, req) {
   while (var row = getRow()) {
      send(row)
   }
}
```

but I'm not sure, and that doesn't sound right because I don't use `head` and `req` anywhere.

Comment: I don't think you will need `head` or `req`, but you need to output a JSON, not only the rows: `{ rows: [ ... ] }`.

Comment: @Dusty: No, I want to tweak a view very slightly, and in order to do that, I need to understand how to send the results of a view verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example list function. It's purpose is to do an intersection of tags, you pass in a key (as the view key), and extra_keys which are the additional tags to include in the intersection. I am just telling this as the purpose of this view does not relate to your question, but it will help you understand what you are looking at.

The list mimics view output, mostly. My app only really looks at rows, so that is the only property I add. YMMV. You can cut the cruft in the middle, if you like. The example is here:

https://github.com/ryanramage/eckoit/blob/master/app.js#L209

Answer (score 0):

I found [this blog post](http://geekiriki.blogspot.com/2010/08/couchdb-using-list-functions-to-sort.html) which seems to be close to what you want.  The only difference would be that in the real view results there is a `total_rows` and `offset` field (as long as there isn't a reduce function).